# Understanding the spring profile

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

I have basic idea how spring profile works. But here in this file this `-` i am not able to get it. And current `Application.yml` file mentioning the three profile which one will get active and when that i need to know as well. Below is the Application.yml file content.

```
spring:
  application:
       name:
  profiles:
    active:
      -default
      -local
      -swaggerinfo
```

Note: i have three config files present in my resources. Also if i want to look another config file
then spring use the naming convention like `Application-<Name>.extension` . so `-` is already get added for the new config file then why we explicitly need
to put another one in our application.yml file under `spring.profile.active`.

Below are the names of the three config files present under the resources folder.

```
application.yml
application-local.yml
bootstrap-default.yml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But here in this file this - i am not able to get it. spring use the
> naming convention like Application-.extension . so - is already
> get added for the new config file then why we explicitly need to put
> another one in our application.yml file under spring.profile.active
>
> ```
> spring:
>   application:
>        name:
>   profiles:
>     active:
>       -default
>       -local
>       -swaggerinfo
> ```

The declaration of profiles are incorrect. You must either put space or should not use (-) at all.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - default
      - local
      - swaggerinfo
```

The Spring also supports the following way of declarations.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: default,local,swaggerinfo
```

or

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: 
      default
      local
      swaggerinfo
```

Here default refers to `application.properties` file not `bootstrap-default.properties`. Also, You don't need to specify the default profile. Spring automatically use `application.properties` as default one. So, in your case it's appropriate to go with `local` and `swaggerinfo`.

> current Aplication.yml file mentioning the three profile which one
> will get active and when that i need to know as well.

Let's talk about the following declaration.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - local
      - swaggerinfo
```

Both `local` and `swaggerinfo` profiles will be active for props loading. So,which means that all the three files (`application.yml` by default) will be consumed by spring.

Let's talk about the order.
The order in the above case would be

**`application -> application-local -> application-swaggerinfo`**

**Note:**
Assume that you've mentioned the same prop in all the three files then in that case the precedence will be given as per the order highlighted above i.e prop mentioned in the `application-swaggerinfo` will override the ones available in the other twos.